# How to/where to add the insert text function in Google docs API

Tags: python, google-api, google-docs-api

I copy pasted from the google api and in my code I verify the user using a token and then right after that I do this code

```
text1="text"
text2="bruh"
text3="reee"
requests = [
     {
        'insertText': {
            'location': {
                'index': 25,
            },
            'text': text1
        }
    },
             {
        'insertText': {
            'location': {
                'index': 50,
            },
            'text': text2
        }
    },
             {
        'insertText': {
            'location': {
                'index': 75,
            },
            'text': text3
        }
    },
]

result = service.documents().batchUpdate(
    documentId=DOCUMENT_ID, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

but I keep getting an error code that says

```
    "Invalid requests[0].insertText: Index 25 must be less than the end index of the referenced segment, 2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the segment you are trying to insert text into is only two characters long, and that you can't insert anything at index 25, because a string two characters long only has indexes 0 and 1. If you change the index to 0 or 1, it should work (at least for the first request).

[Start and End Index explained in the Docs](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/concepts/structure#start_and_end_index)